# Probability of guessing 4-digit code

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Super-simple question, I just want to be sure that I'm right. We want to find a 4-digit code, so we can choose numbers from 0 to 9, but repetition are not allowed and the order does not matter. We want to find the probability of guessing right the number after $t$ trials.

The probability in the first trial is

$\frac{1}{\frac{n!} {k!(n − k)!} } = 1/210$

can we say then that the probability in $t$ trials is $1/(210-(t-1))$? Does someone want to propose a more general formula? Thanks.

Comment: If you fail on the first attempt, can you compute the Pr of failing on the second attempt ?

Comment: By `can we say then that the probability in t trials is` you mean the probability in the trial number `t` given that you fail in all previous ones?

Comment: Order does not matter? So as long as you guess all $4$ digits without guessing their order, it is ok?

Comment: If so your first trial probability is fine. Now just find the probability that you keep failing for $t$ attempts and subtract from $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failing the $k$ first trials has probability
$$\frac{209}{210}\frac{208}{209}\dots\frac{209-k+1}{210-k+1}=\frac{210-k}{210}$$
So the probability to find the code in $k$ trials or less is $\frac{k}{210}$.

Comment: That was my first formula, but then I changed (erroneously) with the posted one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since order does not matter, the problem is exactly equivalent to asking the Pr of winning a $10/4$ lottery if you have purchased $k$ tickets, $$thus\;\; \frac{k}{\binom{10}{4}} = \frac{k}{210}$$